# Show and hide block js.

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I want to show the block
 
user comes with decstop
   
  and hide it
 
  on the phone. With this OK. But on the contrary I do not get.
Sorry for my English.

```
$('#decstop').show();
$('#phone').hide();
if(window.width() <= 480) {
    $('#decstop').hide();
} else {
    $('#phone').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify what happens to all elements for every condition.
Also, $(window), not window.

```
$('#decstop').show();
$('#phone').hide();

if( $(window).width() <= 480 ) {
    $('#decstop').hide();
    $('#phone').show();
} else {
    $('#decstop').show();
    $('#phone').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(window).width()`, instead of `window.width()`, in your control statement.